Load Balancer target group issue
After creating target group and adding the instances to the target group, it was issuing that instances in the target group as unhealthy. I tried resolving it but no luck. can anyone help me with that.
I tried changing inbound rules but no luck. Health check of the target group is getting unhealthy.

Did you configure the health check in the target group? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

It would be helpful as well if you include a screenshot of your target group settings.

This can happen if the Security Group on your EC2 instances does not permit access from the Load Balancer. Are you sure it is configured correctly?

I'll share the screenshots of the security group settings and its configuration settings

I'll try again today and let you guys know about it.
